# In included file: 'begin_code.h' file not found occurring in Neovim LSP

Tags: c, neovim, clangd

I am trying to set up my Neovim for C development however, whenever I use: #include <SDL2/SDL.h> I get an error saying "In included file: 'begin_code.h' file not found".
I did some digging and in my include files and I did see 'begin_code.h'. I am just very confused, could be because I am new to C.

[Screenshot of diagnostic message from Neovim's LSP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeneN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, clangd can not find this headers. clangd needs specific files to find where your header file is.

According to [clangd documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html), you can either generate a `compile_commands.json` file for your project or use `compile_flags.txt`.

For simple project, using `compile_flags.txt` is sufficient. Your compile flags are written one per line. A sample `compile_flags.txt` looks like this:

```
-Wall
-std=c++11
-L/usr/local/lib
-I/usr/local/include
-lfmt
```